# After adding kendo file upload package for angular getting following error at the time of build

Tags: angular, kendo-angular-ui

I have added the following **@progress/kendo-angular-upload**
After adding the package & trying the command build

Following is my package.json file

> 

```
                    {
                    "name": "client-app",
                    "version": "0.0.0",
                    "scripts": {
                        "ng": "ng",
                        "start": "ng serve --port 4203",
                        "build": "ng build --deploy-url /Scripts/AngularJs/ --output-hashing none",
                        "buildw": "ng build --deploy-url /Scripts/AngularJs/ --output-hashing none --watch",
                        "watch": "ng build --deploy-url /Scripts/AngularJs/ --output-hashing none --watch --configuration development",
                        "test": "ng test"
                    },
                    "private": true,
                    "dependencies": {
                        "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
                        "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.0",
                        "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
                        "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
                        "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
                        "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
                        "@angular/localize": "~12.2.0",
                        "@angular/material": "^11.2.3",
                        "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
                        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
                        "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^6.0.0",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^2.0.3",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^5.3.0",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^5.2.3",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^5.0.0",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^4.0.0",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^5.5.1",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-icons": "^0.4.4",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-indicators": "^1.1.1",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^7.0.0",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^3.1.3",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^3.0.4",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^3.0.0",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^6.3.6",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "^3.0.3",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-messages": "^1.32.2",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-pager": "^3.0.3",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^3.0.0",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^4.0.6",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^2.0.0",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "^4.1.3",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^3.1.6",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^5.0.0",
                        "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^8.0.1",
                        "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.0.0",
                        "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.0.0",
                        "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.0.2",
                        "@progress/kendo-svg-icons": "^0.1.2",
                        "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^4.42.0",
                        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
                        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
                        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
                    },
                    "devDependencies": {
                        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.14",
                        "@angular/cli": "~12.2.14",
                        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
                        "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
                        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
                        "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
                        "karma": "~6.3.0",
                        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
                        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
                        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
                        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
                        "typescript": "~4.3.5"
                    }
                    }
```

And after running the following command **npm run build** I m getting the following error

[image]

i have tried deletin node modules & package.lock.json & doing npm i again but still facing same
issue

if i remove the the upload package then it will be building the application sucessfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing this same issue yesterday, and after some research I decided to install the version prior to the latest version and that worked for me (installed version 8.0.2 instead of 9.0.2).
I'm not sure if this is a bug that came with version 9.0.2, but installing version 8.0.2 seemed to work for me.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying i will check it & let you know